# Laravel queu not working when .env is set to QUEUE_CONNECTION=database, but queu is saved to jobs table in database, but job does not execute

Tags: php, laravel, queue

> This is my config queue file. the queue is not working when I change
> my connection to database. it only works when I use sync but it
> doesn't run in the background. How do I make this work in the background? or how do I fix this problem?

```
<?php

return [

    

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

    ],

    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute queue run following command:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Comment: When I run this command, it does nothing.

Comment: Can you share your code of job.

Comment: It works now, but I don't want to run this command the whole time, is there a way to run this command in a cronjob?

Comment: You can run command like this:
`php /path/to/laravel/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty`

Comment: I mean I want to run this command in my code not on the command line, I tried to do it but it does not run on  the background. I need to make the queue:work run on the background in code

Comment: If you have linux sever run command in background append **&** end of the command
`php /path/to/laravel/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty &`

Comment: How can I look for new queus and automaticly run the queus when added to the jobs table?

Comment: nvm it works with this command php artisan queue:work --daemon thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the setting worker listen to your process.

```
ps aux | grep php
```

Set worker listen:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=queu_name --tries=1 --memory=128 --timeout=300
```